# opening a modal without toggling page scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code to freeze entire background while a modal element is visible.

```
function overlay() {
    $('#container').css({'pointer-events' : 'none', 'opacity' : 0.5});
    $('html').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
}
```

it works but with very ugly effect - each time a modal is opening / closing  - page scrollbar is toggling and moves entire html content right or left.

Any better solution?

Comment: Why don't you use another DOM element say `.overlay`, add a semi-transparent background to it and show it? Sample implementation: https://codepen.io/phartiyalpankaj/pen/yEMXew

Comment: @PankajPhartiyal, I want to prevent scrolling page while a modal is open.